# Can't return the path of recorded file by Android App launched from Web Browser

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, recorder, input-type-file

I built an android app that is called from the browser precisely from an input type file element, this app will record a sound and after recording the app should return and set the path of the recorded file to the caller input type file.
My android app is launched successfully, and records the sounds, the file are stored in the external sd card, and of course I can play the recorded files, the problem I have is that the app never returns the path of the recorded file, it returns a path of a file with a name generated by timestamp and other code, with JPG extension, and with 0 bytes of length, not sure why JPG I dont use camera for anything.
I know that this solution will work only in Chrome starting some versions of Android, I need a solution like this. Can you please help me why it is returning a JPG file of 0 bytes instead of the path of the recorded file with extension 3gp, tell me what I'm doing wrong.
Here is my form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input name="mediafilecaller" class='media_mobile_file' type='file' accept='audio/*;capture=microphone'  /><br />
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

This is my android app's manifest xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.apps.audio_recorder_2"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="20"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                  android:exported="true"
                  android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
                >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My main.xml layout is this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/layout" android:background="#1c1d1c">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:id="@+id/msg" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Start recording"
            android:id="@+id/startBtn" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/recordingPicture" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:src="@drawable/recording"
            android:visibility="gone"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Stop recording"
            android:id="@+id/finishBtn" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Play recording"
            android:id="@+id/playBtn" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Stop playback"
            android:id="@+id/stopBtn" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:visibility="gone"
            android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
    <Button
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="Back to TRC"
            android:id="@+id/backBtn" android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" android:onClick="buttonTapped"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my code

```
package com.apps.audio_recorder_2;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.media.MediaRecorder;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private MediaRecorder recorder;
    private String OUTPUT_FILE;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        OUTPUT_FILE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/audiofile.3gp";
        Intent receivedIntent = getIntent();
        String receivedType = receivedIntent.getType();
        System.out.println(receivedType);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        System.out.println("Not sure how to close the activity and send the path pf the recorded file to the web form, precisely to the input type file that launched the app");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0){
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if(extras != null) {
                System.out.println("How return the recorded file");
            }
        }

        this.finish();
    }

    public void buttonTapped(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){
            case R.id.startBtn:
                try{
                    findViewById(R.id.playBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.stopBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.recordingPicture).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    findViewById(R.id.finishBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    beginRecording();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.finishBtn:
                try{
                    findViewById(R.id.recordingPicture).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.finishBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    findViewById(R.id.playBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    stopRecording();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.playBtn:
                try{
                    findViewById(R.id.stopBtn).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playRecording();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.stopBtn:
                try{
                    findViewById(R.id.stopBtn).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    stopPlayback();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.backBtn:
                try {
                    System.out.println("Here is when I tap the Back Button, I need to send the recorded file path to the input type file");
                    Intent databackIntent = new Intent();
                    databackIntent.putExtra("data", OUTPUT_FILE);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK, databackIntent);
                    startActivityForResult(databackIntent, 111);
                    finish();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void stopPlayback() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null)
            mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    private void playRecording() throws Exception{
        ditchMediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUT_FILE);
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }

    private void ditchMediaPlayer() {
        if(mediaPlayer != null){
            try{
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void stopRecording() {
        if(recorder != null)
            recorder.stop();
    }

    private void beginRecording() throws Exception{
        ditchMediaRecorder();
        File outFile = new File(OUTPUT_FILE);

        if(outFile.exists())
            outFile.delete();

        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUT_FILE);
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
    }

    private void ditchMediaRecorder() {
        if(recorder != null){
            recorder.release();
        }
    }
}
```

I spent more than 4 days looking for a solution. I'm pretty sure that I need to put something in the onActivityResults function or in the case case R.id.backBtn in the function buttonTapped. Please help.

Thanks in advance guys.

EDIT:
I commented my onActivityResult method and I changed the code of the R.id.backBtn case to

```
String sharePath = OUTPUT_FILE;
Uri uri = Uri.parse(sharePath);
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("audio/*");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
finish();
```

Now it takes the recorded file for sharing by email, bluetooh, etc., I want return that file to the input type file invoker. No more JPG file returned now but nothing is returned.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the 0 bytes JPG files have names like:
1429560171771-1861914115.jpg  the timestamp is 1429560171 Mon, 20 Apr 2015 20:02:51 GMT. Other example:
1429560160074-148746302.jpg the timestamp is 1429560160 Mon, 20 Apr 2015 20:02:40 GMT

Answer (score 0):

I will answer my own question for those who could have the same problem like me. For this requirement is not necessary to have a function onActivityResult  so I just removed it, and I worked in the case of R.id.backBtn, there the only code should be:

```
case R.id.backBtn:
    try {
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, new Intent().setData(Uri.fromFile(new File(OUTPUT_FILE))));
        finish();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    break;
```

That's everything, I tested with Android 2.3.3 and above and using as minimum Android SDK version 10, working like a charm using Chrome. Cheers.